# Quickbook Drupal Commerce 2 Module

Tags: drupal, quickbooks-online

I’m setting up a commerce 2 site with Drupal 10.1.8, and would like it to sync to my Quickbooks account.

anyone have a working module that can do that?

ot looks like Drupal 7 has some stable versions, but 10 is kinda lacking

I was able to use [this one](https://github.com/intuit/QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK/blob/master/README.md), but it seems to not want to connect to QBO. It also seems deprecated

I looked at a lot of modules but none of them seem to work with QBO out of the box. The one I liked above installed fine, but when I try and connect it gives me an error that says "The redirect_uri query parameter value is invalid". Seems to be a known issue.

Has anyone else made it work?